# what does the e mean in $2.392537302040576$e$+16$?

Tags: graphing-functions

Please help me,
I need to understand how to do this math skill.
Thank you.
I assure you that it is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and is shorthand for

$$\times 10^{16}$$

So for example, `1.77e+3`$ = 1.77 \times 10^3 = 1770$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a number like:
$$p.qrstuvw \ e+x$$
(where $p.qrstuvw$ is some random decimal number), it means
$$p.qrstuvw\times 10^x$$
Your number:
$$2.392537302040576e+16$$
means:
$$2.392537302040576\times 10^{16}$$
I see this $e$ notation a lot when using a graphing calculator app on my iPad. When I "zoom out" a lot, these kinds of numbers are labeled in the x and y axes:
$$5.07412e+9$$
That just means:
$$5.07412\times 10^9$$
Note: This $e$ is *not* Euler's number